# LiveData. Observer doesn't see new data after refresh from API or DB

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, android-livedata, swiperefreshlayout

I need to refresh data using `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `LiveData`. First, the data is loaded and assigned to the `_profile` variable in the `ProfileFragmentViewModel`. Then displayed in `Resource.Status.SUCCESS` block. There are no problems here.

When i use `viewModel.refreshProfile()`, there is no visible effect, that is, the data is not assigned to `_profile` variable in the `ProfileFragmentViewModel`.

I want new data to be loaded into the Observable. Please tell me what my mistake is and how to fix it. Thanks

**ProfileFragment.kt**

```
class ProfileFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: ProfileFragmentViewModel

    private val observer = Observer<Resource<Profile>> {
        when (it.status) {
            Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                Timber.i("Loading...")
            }
            Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                Timber.i("Success: %s", it.data)
                srl_profile.isRefreshing = false
            }
            Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                Timber.i("Error: %s", it.message)
                srl_profile.isRefreshing = false
            }
        }
    };

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        srl_profile.setOnRefreshListener {
           srl_profile.isRefreshing = true
           viewModel.refreshProfile()
        }
        viewModel.getProfileLive().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
    }
}
```

**ProfileFragmentViewModel.kt**

```
class ProfileFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val profileUseCase: ProfileUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _profile = profileUseCase.getProfile()
  
    fun refreshProfile() {
       _profile = profileUseCase.getProfile()
    }
    fun getProfileLive() = _profile
}
```

**ProfileUseCase.kt**

```
class ProfileUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val profileRepository: ProfileRepository
) {

    fun getProfile(): LiveData<Resource<Profile>> {
        return profileRepository.getProfile()
    }
}
```

**ProfileRepository.kt**

```
class ProfileRepository @Inject constructor(   
   private val loginUserDao: LoginUserDao,   
   private val profileDao: ProfileDao   
) {

fun getProfile(): LiveData<Resource<Profile>> =
    liveData(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        emit(Resource.loading(data = null))

        val profile = profileDao.getProfile()

        // Emit Success result...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use LiveData in your ViewModel class

Comment: @Sarah i think, for my case it violates principles of Clean Architecture. Could you please provide more details about your answer?